# Perl String Replace?

Tags: regex, json, perl, replace

I have my string as below, I want to remove the first { with nothing only the first one which is the beginning of string. The string prints fine before replacement but after replacement its empty string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = {"something":[{"some":"12","some":"something","data":"","data":"data2","age":"23"},{......},{.....}]}

# the string is valid as it is json from some array function.

print $string."\n";   #My string prints fine here
 $string = s/\{//;

print "String after replacement".".$string." testing";
```

Comment: Technically `$string` in this case is a hash reference, not a string.

Comment: This is not your original code, because this code does not compile. The `$string` assignment is an unquoted json string, and the last `print` statement contains 5 quotation marks. Don't post anything but the exact code that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than trying to manually mess with the JSON, I strongly suggest you use an existing, tested, debugged JSON module to read in the JSON, modify the data structure, and write it back out.

See [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON) for one module that will do it for you.

Comment: There's https://metacpan.org/module/JSON::XS too, I guess it's quicker than `JSON`

Comment: `JSON::XS` also handles utf-8 better than `JSON`

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
$string = s/\{//;
```

with:

```
$string =~ s/\{//;
```

Comment: Oh man, I spend half an hour figuring that out yesterday...;)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I wanted that simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before in the thread, another approach is to use [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON::XS) module, it will be faster
 than `JSON` and moreover like [redbmk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817950/redbmk) said, it handles UTF-8 better.

Comment: From `JSON` docs: *This module try to use `JSON::XS` by default and fail to it, use `JSON::PP` instead. So its features completely depend on `JSON::XS` or `JSON::PP`.*